# tkinter : progressbar with different colors

Tags: tkinter, colors, progress-bar, sections

I use in this program a Progressbar in connextion to the scale. What I want is that from 0 to 25 the progressbar be green, from 25 to 50 yellow, from 50 to 75 orange and from 75 to 100 red, but I looking for the different sections have their own color, and not all the progressbar changes its color, like in this programm (so at the end, if the scale is on 65 for example, the progressbar will have a green section, a yellow section and an orange section).
I have absolutely no idea of how to do that, and found absolutely nothing.

Thank you if you can help me !!!!!!

Here the programm I have :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def volumelevel(scalevar):
    scalevar=int(scalevar)
    if scalevar <= 25:
        s.configure("Horizontal.TProgressbar",background="green")
        progress.configure(style="Horizontal.TProgressbar",value=scalevar)
    elif scalevar <= 50:
        s.configure("Horizontal.TProgressbar",background="yellow")
        progress.configure(style="Horizontal.TProgressbar",value=scalevar)
    elif scalevar <= 75:
        s.configure("Horizontal.TProgressbar",background="orange")
        progress.configure(style="Horizontal.TProgressbar",value=scalevar)
    elif scalevar <= 100:
        s.configure("Horizontal.TProgressbar",background="red")
        progress.configure(style="Horizontal.TProgressbar",value=scalevar)

root=Tk()

s=ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use("clam")

progress=ttk.Progressbar(root,maximum="100",style="Horizontal.TProgressbar")
progress.pack()

scalevar=IntVar()
scale=Scale(root,from_=0,to=100,orient="horizontal",variable=scalevar,command=volumelevel)
scale.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `progressbar` can not do this,but `tkinter.canvas` can do this easily.

It is the Image:

[image]

and

[image]

Is this what you want?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def volumelevel(scalevar):
    scalevar=int(scalevar)
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    if scalevar <= 25:
        canvas.create_rectangle(0,5,scalevar,15,fill="green")
    elif scalevar <= 50 and scalevar > 25:
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 5, 25, 15, fill="green")
        canvas.create_rectangle(25, 5, scalevar,15 ,fill="yellow")
    elif scalevar <= 75 and scalevar > 50:
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 5, 25, 15, fill="green")
        canvas.create_rectangle(25, 5, 50, 15, fill="yellow")
        canvas.create_rectangle(50, 5, scalevar, 15, fill="orange")
    else:
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 5, 25, 15, fill="green")
        canvas.create_rectangle(25, 5, 50, 15, fill="yellow")
        canvas.create_rectangle(50, 5, 75, 15, fill="orange")
        canvas.create_rectangle(75, 5, scalevar, 15, fill="red")

root=Tk()

s=ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use("clam")

canvas = Canvas(root,bd=1,relief="solid",width=98,height=15) # I find when width=98 can make canvas filled when scale = 100;
canvas.pack()

scalevar=IntVar()
scale=Scale(root,from_=0,to=100,orient="horizontal",variable=scalevar,command=volumelevel)
scale.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes exactly something like that !! Thank you !!